# Is it possible to restrict user from to bookmark a specific web page?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am developing a webpage with Python(Django) and want to restrict users from to be able to bookmark a specific web page. Is there a solution?

Comment: what would be the difference between the user accessing the page through a link/bookmark and by entering the url from memory into the address bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookmarks are Browser specific and you cannot intervene with what the user can do with the browser outside of your web application.

If you do not want the user to access the webpage directly, you can implement Authorization with Session IDs to prevent direct access to the specific webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, the user can always bookmark a page because it is a browser function.

But you can use sessions. Then make sure that any page request must have an active session ID, otherwise, it will return an error or redirect to the home page.

The user can add a bookmark to the page, but the bookmarks will only work for limited time. He won't able to access the page after the session timeout. This also has the added benefit of making the site impossible to index by the search engines.